# Como hago para imprimir mi piramide de numeros en un div de html?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que hacer un programa que imprima en una piramide de N numeros, el usuario indica el número de pisos y se mostraria algo asi.
1
22
333
4444
55555
Hice mi codigo y lo hace solamente imprimiendo con el document.write. Yo quiero imprimirlo de alguna forma en mi index y no que me habra otra pagina.
Aqui esta mi codigo.

```
 document.querySelector("#generar").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var num=Number(document.querySelector("#numero").value);
    var i, a;

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

        for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {

             document.write(i); 
        }

                        document.write("<br>"); 
    }

});
```

---

Muchas gracias, ya lo probe de esa forma y si funciono. De hecho ya lo habia intentando pero no me habia percatado que en el div no le puse "id" si no class y por eso me marcaba error, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No utilices `document.write`, ya que esta función borra todo lo que tienes en tu documento antes de escribir algo. Crea un `div` en donde escribirás tu resultado utilizando `innerHTML` cada vez que el usuario presione el botón `generar`.

Te adjunto una posible solución:

```js
let resultado = document.querySelector("#resultado")
document.querySelector("#generar").addEventListener("click", function () {
  resultado.innerHTML = "";
  var num = Number(document.querySelector("#numero").value);
  var i, a;
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for (a = 0; a < i; a++) {
      resultado.innerHTML += i;
    }
    resultado.innerHTML += "<br>";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='number' id='numero'>
<button id="generar">Generar</button>

<div id="resultado"></div>
```